# How to hide device back functionality in jquery mobile tab (navbar)?

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have developed jquery mobile tab to my page. If my page having 5 tabs, now I'm in 3rd tab. I would like it so that when I press the back button from mobile, it should automatically redirect to the 2nd and 1st tab. Then it should redirect to my home page like another html page.

When I press the back button from device, it'll automatically redirect to my home page not a previous tab page. How to control in jquery mobile? Please do the needful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to listen to `navigate` event and check if *back* button was pressed from *data* object `data.state.direction`. If true, `$.mobile.changePage()` to *homepage*.

If you're using jQuery Mobile 1.4, `$.mobile.pageContiner.pagecontainer("change", "#page");`

```
$(window).on("navigate", function (event, data) {
  if (data.state.direction == "back") {
    $.mobile.changePage("#homepage");
    return false; /* prevent showing previous page */
  }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/NMk26/show)**